# Orthogonal Coordinates with Constant Magnitude Basis Vectors

Tags: coordinate-systems, orthogonality, curvilinear-coordinates

I have been doing some work in curvilinear coordinates and I often encounter orthogonal coordinates (which are obviously super convenient). I am of course familiar with the usual suspects like cylindrical, spherical, and polar coordinates, but all of these coordinates have a particular thing in common that makes them less than ideal; their Jacobian determinant is something other than $1$, or specifically is nonconstant. Equivalently, we can say that the tangent vectors $\frac{\partial{\bf r}}{\partial y^i}$ are orthogonal, but not constant. It got me wondering about orthogonal transformations in which the Jacobian determinant is constant, or the coordinate tangent vectors are constant.

There are some obvious transformations: for $\mathbb{R}^n$, any transformation from ${\bf x}\to{\bf y}$ of the form

$${\bf y}={\bf x}_0+R{\bf x}$$

where $R$ is an orthogonal matrix is a valid coordinate transformation and the new coordinates are orthogonal coordinates. To show this, the basis vectors are

$$\frac{\partial{\bf r}}{\partial y^i}=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\partial {\bf r}}{\partial x^j}\frac{\partial x^j}{\partial y^i}=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\partial x^j}{\partial y^i}{\bf e}_j$$

where ${\bf e}_j$ is the $j^{th}$ standard basis vector $(0,...,1,...,0)$ with a $1$ in position $j$. The inverse of the transform is

$${\bf x}=R^T{\bf y}-R^T{\bf x}_0\implies\frac{\partial x^j}{\partial y^i}=R_{ij}$$

So

$$\frac{\partial {\bf r}}{\partial y^i}=\sum_{j=1}^nR_{ij}{\bf e}_j=R_i$$

where $R_{ij}$ is row $i$ column $j$ of $R$ and $R_i$ is the entire row $i$ of $R$. Since $R$ is an orthogonal matrix the rows are all orthogonal, these vectors are all orthogonal.

So it's clear that the given transformation creates orthogonal tangent vectors, since it amounts to a displacement and rotation. The question I have is whether this constitutes *all* such orthogonal coordinates.

The question is: suppose I have a new set of coordinates for $\mathbb{R}^n$ $(u^1,...,u^n)$ with the property that the vectors $\partial{\bf r}/\partial u^i$ are a collection of orthonormal vectors (enforcing normality for simplicity). Does this imply that these coordinates can be computed from a translation and a rotation from the standard coordinates?

I haven't really been able to show anything useful. Any thoughts are appreciated!

**Edit**: I can at least supply the information that I would know. In general, to have an orthonormal set of coordinates $(u^1,...,u^n)$, we require two things: orthogonality and normality, so

$$\frac{\partial{\bf r}}{\partial u^i}\cdot\frac{\partial{\bf r}}{\partial u^j}=\delta_{ij}$$

so

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{m=1}^n\frac{\partial x^k}{\partial u^i}\frac{\partial x^m}{\partial u^j}\frac{\partial{\bf r}}{\partial x^k}\cdot\frac{\partial{\bf r}}{\partial x^m}=\delta_{ij}$$

As we have $\partial{\bf r}/\partial x^k={\bf e}_k$, this is

$$\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{\partial x^k}{\partial u^i}\frac{\partial x^k}{\partial u^j}=\delta_{ij}$$

If $J$ is the Jacobian matrix for the transformation in the form

$$J=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{\partial x^1}{\partial u^1} & \cdots & \frac{\partial x^n}{\partial u^1} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{\partial x^1}{\partial u^n} & \cdots & \frac{\partial x^n}{\partial u^n}
\end{array}\right)$$

This then means $JJ^T=I$, which makes sense: if the Jacobian matrix is orthogonal, then the coordinates remain orthogonal. The question then is: **does there exist a nonconstant orthogonal Jacobian matrix that describes a valid coordinate system for $\mathbb{R}^n$**?

**Edit 2**: Another thing I notice is that we can explicitly find the inverse of $J$ by noticing

$$\delta^i_j=\frac{\partial u^i}{\partial u^j}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\partial u^i}{\partial x^k}\frac{\partial x^k}{\partial u^j}$$

which tells us that

$$J^{-1}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{\partial u^1}{\partial x^1} & \cdots & \frac{\partial u^n}{\partial x^1} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{\partial u^1}{\partial x^n} & \cdots & \frac{\partial u^n}{\partial x^n}
\end{array}\right)$$

Since we also know $J^T=J^{-1}$, this means

$$\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial u^j}=\frac{\partial u^j}{\partial x^i}$$

I don't know if this is helpful, but it's definitely an interesting relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Jacobian is a rotation (an element of $SO(n)$ or $O(n)$), the pulled back metric is $R^T R=I$. So you have an isometry to the Euclidean space, which if you are mapping from nD to nD, means that it can only be a global rotation and translation.

Comment: Thanks for your response! From what I see, this means that the coordinate transform is *locally* an isometry, but we haven't justified that the transformation is the same everywhere, although my intuition would say that has to be the case. If there a way we can make this more rigorous?

Comment: The intrinsic curvature is zero. So it's globally isometric to Euclidean.

Comment: I'm looking for some more details to be able to understand this more in depth. Can you write up a deeper explanation (more than just an intuition) or cite some sources?

Comment: If the Jacobian $J$ satisfies $J^T J=I$, you have an isometry (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding#Riemannian_and_pseudo-Riemannian_geometry). If you have an isometry between Euclidean spaces, it is one element of the Euclidean group (rigid transformation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_group),

Comment: Alright, I'm almost fully on board. Since the coordinates $u$ map to all of $\mathbb{R}^n$, we have an isometry on Euclidean space, so the transform is an element of the Euclidean group, which is a rotation and a displacement, which is exactly what I want. The last thing I'm shaky on is how can we show that this transform $u:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is actually surjective? We would need this to justify that this is an isometry, right?

Comment: For any region covered by the coordinates $u$, it would work. Perhaps it is easier to see by thinking of the coordinate curves, where you fix $n-1$ coordinates. Since the metric representation is still the identity matrix, the associated Christoffel symbols are all 0's, so the coordinate curves are actually geodesics (straight lines). You can see the coordinate curve network is just formed by a bunch of straight lines (along which the coordinates change with unit speed).

Comment: Getting the coordinate curves to be a bunch of straight lines is what got be on board. Thanks so much for all of your help!